# Can I ask questions in another language on Super User?

Tags: support

I'm new to Super User. I'm reading rules but there is one big question in my mind: can a user ask a question in another language like French or Spanish?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: [su] is English only. The link in the other comment informs you about other [se] sites.

Answer (score 2):

No. Reasons why are explained in the existing answer that Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 linked to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684

Which is basically a copy of the official policy from [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

(Also Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's link)